# How to decrypt a DRM video file with SHA-256 Algorithm in Android and play the same file

Tags: android, drm, sha256

I have a problem that I have a DRM video file which is encrypted with SHA-256(512 bytes) algorithm I have to decrypt it and play the same video. I am new to Android that's why I can't understand it and unable to proceed further regarding the same. Please suggest me the Solution for this or any tutorial for understand the same. Actually my client's need is following:

"**MPEG video**
The transport for this is described below.  The video is DRM’d so that it cannot be widely copied.The DRMoverwrites the header of the video file and addsthe metadata to the end of the file.  The file structurelooks like:

```
<video file><metadata><metadata_offset(i8)><type(i4)>
```

The first 2^21 bytes of the file will be xor-ed with the following pattern.  SHA-256 (512-bit mode) is used to make a 2^11 byte pattern.  The first SHA call will be made on “xyzzy” + the FB username + the UUID of the video + “@a2+;%d3-“ .

The following calls will use the output of the previous stage plus two ASCII bytes representing a counter that starts at 1 and goes to 2^5.  The pattern is then xor-ed across the file 2^10 times.

The type is a four byte integer in network byte order.  It has to be zero for this release."

I am unable to understand what I should do for the above. Please suggest me for the same.

Comment: You're aware that SHA-256 is a hash function, that means it can only be encrypted but **NOT** decrypted?

Comment: @Tseng: They're using SHA-256 to generate encryption keys based on known inputs.

Comment: Yes Tseng I know that SHA-256 can not be decrypted but I have to play the video. Can you suggest me how?